# Access object attributes in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I would like to achieve something that in python looks like this:

```
person = Person.name('Thomas')
```

In my views.py I'm passing every `People` object that matches the query and list with few names. Then, I want to access specific object and it's fields, i.e. sex, age, city of this particular person. So far I've tried defining custom filter like this:

```
@register.filter(name='people_attributes')
def object_attributes(val):
    return Person.objects.get(name=val)
```

My goal is to be able to loop over list with values and then, during every iteration, access coresponding object. Let's say, my list looks like `['John', 'Adam', 'Alice', 'Katherine']`, I want to access object which `name` attribute is equal to John, Adam, Alice or Katherine.

Comment: Why don't you generate such list of `Person`s in the `views.py`?

Comment: This list of names is generated inside `views.py` but there's another thing - I want this list to have fixed number of elements (for this purpose, let's say 3). By generating just list of `Person` names attributes, it can be anywhere from 0 to 3. I'm generating such list and then filling it with `None` values until it reaches said count.

Comment: well you can do that in a view, and leter `map(...)` your name through such `Person.objects.get(..)`. Typically templates should only be used to render things, not to perform much semantical things.

Comment: You're right, I can create dictionary, where key would be person's name and as value I can pass desired object just fine.